# How to close a connection of a client when multiple clients are connected?

Tags: python

I am having a multi-client server which listens to multiple clients. Now if to one server 5 clients are connected and I want to close the connection between the server and just one client then how am I going to do that.
My server code is:

```
import socket
import sys
from thread import *
try:
   s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
except socket.error,msg:
   print "Socket Creation Error"
   sys.exit();

print 'Socket Created'
host = ''
port = 65532

try:
   s.bind((host, port))
except socket.error,msg:
   print "Bind Failed";
   sys.exit()

print "Socket bind complete"

s.listen(10)
print "Socket now listening"

def clientthread(conn):
   i=0
   while True:

      data = conn.recv(1024)
      reply = 'OK...' + data
      conn.send(reply)
      print data

while True:
   conn, addr = s.accept()
   start_new_thread(clientthread,(conn,))

conn.close()
s.close()
```

Comment: the thread module is deprecated, use threading instead.

Comment: to close the connection call `conn.close()`

Comment: @Daniel: I have used conn.close() but this will close the connection for all the clients, but I want to close the connection for just one client.

Comment: how have you done this, 'cause every client has its own *conn*.

Comment: @Daniel: exactly now if I want to check that If a client has send more than 4 messages then server will close its connection.Now how am I gonna do this.See I just want to close the connection of that client who has send me more than 4 messages.

Comment: First of all you have to introduce a protocol. TCP is a streaming protocol, which by definition has no messages. Then you have to count the messages, and do a `conn.close()` after you have reached 4.